# Error in Installing Package

Tags: software-installation, bluetooth, ralink

```
chathuranga@chathuranga-HP-1000-Notebook-PC:~/rtbth-3.9.3$ make && make install

make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-30-generic/build M=/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.o
/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c: In function ‘rtbt_hci_dev_receive’:
/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c:216:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘hci_recv_frame’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  status = hci_recv_frame(skb);
  ^
In file included from /home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/include/hps_bluez.h:32:0,
                 from /home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c:29:
include/net/bluetooth/hci_core.h:768:5: note: expected ‘struct hci_dev *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sk_buff *’
 int hci_recv_frame(struct hci_dev *hdev, struct sk_buff *skb);
     ^
/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c:216:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘hci_recv_frame’
  status = hci_recv_frame(skb);
  ^
In file included from /home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/include/hps_bluez.h:32:0,
                 from /home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c:29:
include/net/bluetooth/hci_core.h:768:5: note: declared here
 int hci_recv_frame(struct hci_dev *hdev, struct sk_buff *skb);
     ^
/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c: In function ‘rtbt_hps_iface_init’:
/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c:404:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  hdev->send = rtbt_hci_dev_send;
             ^
/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c:406:6: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘ioctl’
  hdev->ioctl = rtbt_hci_dev_ioctl;
      ^
/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c: At top level:
/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.c:83:20: warning: ‘pkt_type_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static const char *pkt_type_str[]=
                    ^
make[2]: *** [/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3/rtbth_core_bluez.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/chathuranga/rtbth-3.9.3] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This really has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You probably want to file a bug against rtbth with these errors:

```
rtbth_core_bluez.c:216:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘hci_recv_frame’
  status = hci_recv_frame(skb);
rtbth_core_bluez.c:406:6: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘ioctl’
  hdev->ioctl = rtbt_hci_dev_ioctl;
```